# Jenkins "POM_VERSION" variable does not reset from build to build

Tags: maven, jenkins

Following Jenkins documentation  [jenkins docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+maven2+project)
I can use the POM_VERSION environment variable to take the current version from the pom file.

But for some reason the POM_VERSION environment variable is not being refreshed from build to build. for example:
I changed the version number manually but the build number that exported was the last from the previous build.

From my python script:

```
print 'Current version is ' + os.environ['POM_VERSION']
```

which gives the following log `Current version is 0.1.5` which is clearly wrong because i changed it. you can further see it in my maven versions goal output:

> ```
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.1:set (default-cli) @ ep-reporter ---
> [INFO] Searching for local aggregator root...
> [INFO] Local aggregation root: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/exchange-planner-  reporter/workspace
> [INFO] Processing com.exelate:ep-reporter
> [INFO]     Updating project com.company:ep-reporter
> [INFO]         from version 0.1.8 to 0.1.6
> Props: {project.version=0.1.6, project.artifactId=ep-reporter, project.groupId=com.company}
> ```

note that it went from 0.1.5 because i have a script that advances it. but maven clearly states that its changing it from 0.1.8 to 0.1.6 which is not what POM_VERSION says

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That environment variable is set **at the time Jenkins *first* reads your POM file**. You are clearly changing it during the build.

If you are changing it during the build, you *know* what you are changing to, and you should use the same mechanism to display it later.

Comment: first thing that i do in the pre build steps is print it... and it always advances 1 more from the previous build. even though i don't push the new version to git or anything. the pom version does not change. but the variable does

Comment: and what i am saying is that from the first build to the second one this variable is not read again. even though i manually changed the version, it was not picked up on the build see example: i changed it to 0.1.8 what was picked up by jenkins was 0.1.5 (previous build was 1.0.4 i advanced it and pushed)

Comment: @Gleeb I've run into this same problem, if that helps for another data point.

Comment: I think this might be a legit bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24869?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by setting "Check-out Strategy" option to "Always checkout a fresh copy" in Source Code Management section.